# Entities with varied Movement polymorphic implementations in Julia

Tags: beginner, julia, strategy-pattern

I have very basic principle. I have multiple types of entities with some shared functionality. Some of this functionality is highly customizable and you want to be able to swap it out even for a single type.

For example, I have an "Entity" type and subtypes "SmartAgent" and "Agent".

Their instances may or may not have the same functionality for  movement and therefore movement has multiple implementations.
If I was using OOP, I would just pass each one an instance of movement implementation, which does this for me.   For example, one object could be given "*just fly there, ignore obstacles*", and others be given "*move using waypoints*" or "*use pathfinding and then move*".

This is the concept I am trying to implement in Julia (just starting with this language) and this is as far as I got.
The entity type has `get_movement()` method, which returns `Movement` type and that one is used for multiple dispatching in `function movement(entity::Entity, movement_type::Movement)`.

What I especially don't like:

- `Movement` (and subtypes) don't have any fields and can be singletons.
- Its value makes no sense and is never read.
- I have to redefine fields and "getters" for `Entity` type in its subtypes, but I learned this is just how it goes in Julia.

There are also likely other design mistakes in the code as I am a Julia noob (like the usage of typing); please comment on that too.

```
using Test

abstract type Entity
end

abstract type Movement
end

struct MoveByMomentum <: Movement
end
struct NoMovement <: Movement
end

mutable struct Agent <: Entity
    position::AbstractArray{AbstractFloat}
    momentum::AbstractArray{AbstractFloat}
    movement::Movement
end

mutable struct SmarterAgent <: Entity
    position::AbstractArray{AbstractFloat}
    momentum::AbstractArray{AbstractFloat}
    movement::Movement
end

function get_position(entity::Entity)
    return entity.position
end

function get_momentum(entity::Entity)
    return entity.momentum
end

function get_movement(entity::Entity)::Movement
    return entity.movement
end

function update_position(entity::Entity, position::AbstractArray{AbstractFloat})
    entity.position = position
end


function move_by_momentum(entity::Entity)
    position = get_position(entity)
    momentum = get_momentum(entity)
    new_position::AbstractArray{AbstractFloat} = position + momentum
    update_position(entity, new_position)
end

function no_movement(entity::Entity)
    # we don't move
end

function movement(entity::Entity, movement_type::Movement)
    error("unimplemented")
end

function movement(entity::Entity, movement_type::MoveByMomentum)
    move_by_momentum(entity)
end


function movement(entity::Entity, movement_type::NoMovement)
    # we don't move
end

function move(entity::Entity)
    movement(entity, get_movement(entity))
end


@testset "Agents that move by their momentum" begin
    agent = Agent([0, 0], [1, 1], MoveByMomentum())

    @test agent.position == [0.0, 0.0]
    move(agent)
    @test agent.position == [1.0, 1.0]        
end

@testset "Agents that cannot move" begin
    agent = Agent([0, 0], [1, 1], NoMovement())

    @test agent.position == [0.0, 0.0]
    move(agent)
    @test agent.position == [0.0, 0.0]
end
```

Comment: @J_H The comment you provided is a good start to an answer.

Comment: "There are also other mistakes in the code" If the code not woking, it´s off topic.

Comment: Code is executable and working as expected, mistakes are in nature of design and idiomacy.